# Simplify tan$\theta$ cos$\theta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How do I simplify tan$\theta$ cos$\theta$ ?

Why is this  so hard to do? What pieces of information should I know before doing these?

Can someone just tell me were am I going wrong?  I have 5 days to master this before my SAT Practice.

I would brush up on 'basics' but i don't even know how this related to anything ive learnt in trig before...I literally google every identity, am i supposed to remember or somehow derive them??

Comment: Do you remember the definition of tan?

Comment: Do you know how tan relates to sin and cos? (4 days, 23h, 58min)

Comment: http://www.sosmath.com/trig/Trig5/trig5/trig5.html

Comment: To use the 5 days brushing up the basics will be worth more than collecting and memorising possible answers

Comment: I saw your earlier posts. You are going wrong, by not concentrating on the basic definition of sine, cos and tan. If I was you, I would take a pen and paper and start by drawing triangle and learn the ratios of sin,cos and tan. It would not be called maths, if it was not tricky! :)

Comment: @sasha Because of "Why is this so hard to do?" for one of the most easy questions trigonometry can provide?

Comment: @Lord_Gestalter I highly doubt this is one of the easiest questions trigonometry can provide. I am 14.5 years old and this is hard for me to grasp, you are more than twice my age so of course it will be easy for you.

Comment: @sasha Sorry, but if you consider knowing a definition and reducing a fraction complicated I'm afraid we won't be any help for your SAT. I don't really see your effort aprt from googleing, which I suppose won't be allowed at the tests. Brush your basics!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** What is the definition of the $\tan$ function?

Comment: Tan = Opp / Adj..

Comment: @sasha That is a rough definition only true for angles from $0$ to $\frac\pi2$. For other corners, the $\tan$ is defined via the $\cos$ and $\sin$ function. If you are practising for SATs, I advise you to look that definition up.

Comment: @sasha $\tan\theta = opp/adj = \displaystyle\frac{opp}{adj}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{hyp}}{\frac{1}{hyp}} = \frac{\frac{opp}{hyp}}{\frac{opp}{hyp}}=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$

Answer (score 5):

Notice first that the $\tan$ function is defined on $D:=\Bbb R\setminus\{\frac\pi2+k\pi,\; k\in\Bbb Z\}$ and that $\tan\theta=\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$ so

$$\tan\theta\cos\theta=\sin\theta,\quad\forall\theta\in D$$
and be careful the trap is to give a wrong domain.

Comment: I am used to write `-` rather than $\$ for excluding. Anyway +1

Answer (score 1):

Elementary school proof for $\theta \in ]0, \pi/2[$:

Consider a right triangle with angles $\pi/2, \theta, \pi/2-\theta$ and edges lengths $a,b,c>0$ as in the figure below

[image: Right triangle]

Then 
$$\tan(\theta)= \frac{a}{c}, \quad \cos(\theta) = \frac{c}{b}, \quad \sin(\theta) = \frac{a}{b},$$
thus
$$\tan(\theta) \cos(\theta) = \frac{a}{c}\cdot \frac{c}{b} = \frac{a}{b} = \sin(\theta).$$

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this.
Here is one way:

Saying that

$\tan(x)=o/a $ and $ \cos(x)=a/h$, we get $oa/ha = o/h=\sin x$ so the answer is $\sin x$!